# Spot an activity of stock tickers

Tags: equities, correlation, reference-request

I've got 5 minute interval data of the 500 most viewed tickers. I would like to try to correlate changes in place in ranking of given ticker with volatility of underlying asset (for given stock market) and see if it's meaningful predictor. Changes are measured in real time in comparison to last position in EoD rank. I wonder if the simplest approach is suitable (correlation of position delta in rank versus volatility), where any any papers about using such data ?

Comment: This is part of the realm of sentiment analysis. Yes there are studies about this (notably using similar social media activity to predict volatility). Yet, your question is quite off topic since directly tied to the development of trading strategies.

Comment: How do you rank the tickers?

Comment: @LazyCat ranking of number of profile views